# Is it possible to implement a trait on specific characters in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a parser in Rust and I've added some shortcut functions to `char` for creating specific single-character tokens:

```rust
impl CharToToken for char {
    fn to_token(&self, pos: usize) -> Token {
        match *self {
            '{' => Token {
                token_type: TokenType::CurlyBraceOpen,
                span: (pos, pos),
                text: "{",
            },
            '}' => Token {
                token_type: TokenType::CurlyBraceClose,
                span: (pos, pos),
                text: "}",
            },
            ';' => Token {
                token_type: TokenType::SemiColon,
                span: (pos, pos),
                text: ";",
            },
            _ => panic!("Can't create a token from char {:?}", self),
        }
    }
}
```

The intended use case here is just to save some typing. Instead of writing:

```rust
tokens.push(Token {
    token_type: TokenType::CurlyBraceOpen,
    span: (cursor, cursor),
    text: "{",
})
```

I can just write:

```rust
tokens.push('{'.to_token(cursor));
```

The only downside here is that the type system doesn't save me from writing `'X'.to_token(123)` and crashing my application, and I don't really want to return a `Result` and make my logic more verbose. I'd rather the type system prevent me from writing the wrong thing in the first place.

Is there any way to instruct the compiler that this function should only ever be called on the character literals `'{'`, `'}'` and `';'`, rather than allowing any `char`?

Comment: You could put the logic to convert to tokens into a `const` function, which would make the panic produce a compile error instead of a run-time error.

Comment: @jthulhu That's a new concept to me, if you could write a short example in a new answer I'll give it a +1 :)

Comment: Well, actually @drewtato wrote an example of what I said almost at the same time :)

Comment: Characters are not types... [yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/107606).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That doesn't necessarily mean that the compiler can't know about it  For example I've seen compiler errors about array indexes being out of bounds, if the compiler knows the size of the array at compile time. I was hoping something similar might be true for chars. The link you provided, while flying far over my head, sounds like it might be the kind of thing I was thinking about 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* make this work using const generics, but it's a bit verbose.

```rs
fn main() {
    ToToken::<'{'>::to_token(0);
}

struct ToToken<const C: char>;
impl ToToken<'{'> {
    fn to_token(pos: usize) -> Token {
        Token {
            token_type: TokenType::CurlyBraceOpen,
            span: (pos, pos),
            text: "{",
        }
    }
}
```

The impl and the calls can be shortened with macros.

However, you already have all the valid tokens listed out in `TokenType`, so I'd just use that instead:

```rs
TokenType::CurlyBraceOpen.to_token(cursor);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can match against literals in a macro.

```rust
macro_rules! token_type {
    ('{') => {
        TokenType::CurlyBraceOpen
    };
    ('}') => {
        TokenType::CurlyBraceClose
    };
    (';') => {
        TokenType::Semicolon
    };
}

macro_rules! token {
    ($ch:tt, $cursor:expr) => {{
        match $cursor {
            cursor => Token {
                token_type: token_type!($ch),
                span: (cursor, cursor),
                text: &stringify!($ch)[1..2],
            },
        }
    }};
}
```

Example invocations:

```rust
token!('{', 15)
token!('}', 30)
token!(';', 45)
// token!(':', 60)    // compile-time error
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd9c8afca28f488c2eff215bd4b9dba1))

Comment: Ooh that's cool, that makes total sense. Perhaps a `token!` macro is the best fit for my needs.

Comment: This is close to what [the syn crate does](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/token/index.html) but it sadly doesn't work for `{` and `}`, so they'd need to be quoted.